# SharePoint 2013 - Edit TopNavigationBar

Tags: 2013, powershell, navigation

I want to edit an item in the TopNavigationBar with a PowerShell script.
I´m using a Windows Server 2008 R2 (English) with SharePoint 2013 (German).

My PowerShell script says that the Title is changed.
But at the UI is still the old name "OldName". 
When I´m doing a double check with PowerShell, I can see the Title changed to "NewName"

Is there a UI Culture property? How can I change the Title?

Thanks in advance!

```
$Web = Get-SPWeb "https://sharepoint.url"
$tempname = "NewName"

$TopNavigationBar = $Web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar
foreach($NavItem in $TopNavigationBar)
{
    if($NavItem.Title -eq "OldName")
    {
    Write-Host "Change Navigation" -ForegroundColor Green
    $NavItem.Title = $tempname

    $NavItem.Update()
    $TestWeb.Update()
    }
}
$Web.dispose()

#Check
$WebCheck = Get-SPWeb "https://sharepoint.url"
$WebCheck.Navigation.TopNavigationBar
$WebCheck.dispose()
```

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
$Web = Get-SPWeb "https://sharepoint.url"
$tempname = "NewName"

$TopNavigationBar = $Web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar
foreach($NavItem in $TopNavigationBar)
{
    if($NavItem.Title -eq "OldName")
    {
    Write-Host "Change Navigation" -ForegroundColor Green
    $NavItem.Title = $tempname

    $NavItem.Update()
    $web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true
    $Web.Update()
    $web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $false
    }
}
$Web.dispose()

#Check

$WebCheck = Get-SPWeb "https://sharepoint.url"
$WebCheck.Navigation.TopNavigationBar
$WebCheck.dispose()
```

you need to do it same way as you do it though c# , AllowUnsafeUpdates to force changes on a list when you are trying to update the database as a result of the GET request.

equally important is updating the web object and not $TestWeb.Update() :)